# Efficient way to slice a numpy array based on unknown identical values in first column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a relatively large data file on the order of 10GB with three columns that looks something like:

```
X             Y    Z
----          ---- ----
.10000E+05    100  35
.10000E+05    101  45
.             .    .
.             .    .
.             .    .
.10000E+05    400  45
.16730E+05    100  43
.16730E+05    101  25
.             .    .
.             .    .
.             .    .
.16730E+05    400  57
.             .    .
.             .    .
.             .    .
n             100  34
n             101  54
.             .    .
.             .    .
.             .    .
n             400  45
```

So basically, there are two independent variables `X`, `Y` and one dependent `Z`. The data is loaded into a `NumPy` array via:

```
data = np.loadtxt('datafile.txt', skiprows = 2)
```

so the `X`, `Y` and `Z` columns correspond to `data[:,0]`, `data[:,1]` and `data[:,2]` respectively. The `X` column is made up of sections of common `floats` which are unknown ahead of time but are in ascending order, as in the example `(.10000E+05,.16730E+05,...,n)`, that I would like to slice upon resulting in new arrays that have common `X` values.

**What is an efficient way to slice this array as mentioned?**

I have tried a method that relies on looping over the `X` column and checking if neighboring elements are the same, but this takes way to long running in Python.

Comment: Is the first column sorted? Are they all integer numbers? Do you want a new array for each integer number?

Comment: The first column is in ascending order,  they are floats, and a new array for each identical float. I will update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` has some functions, that help you to accomplish your task:

```
borders = data[0,:].searchsorted(numpy.unique(data[0,:]))
part0 = data[borders[0]:borders[1]]
```

But I wouldn't suggest to break the big array apart, but to index into it with `borders`, whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need this but slicing the big array and creating many smaller arrays may not be your best option.

If you really want to do it, you can try to get unique values of the first column and split the array for each unique value.

```
uniq_vals = np.unique(data[:,1])
for u in uniq_vals:
    splitted = data[data[:,1]==u]
    # do whatever you want with `splitted`
```

and this will create a list of lists in one line

```
[data[data[:,1]==u] for u in np.unique(data[:,1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done efficiently using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(data[:, 0]).split(data[:, 1:])
```